# understanding step in Simplex Algorithm

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I am learning the Simplex Algorithm, and currently understand every step except one part. The relevant section from my notes are below. In the second step below, I am not sure why we need to pick $a_{ij}$ to minimise $a_{i0}/a_{ij}$.

My understanding is that, the coefficients of the bottom row should be $0$ for variables in the basis. Therefore, once we have found the variable with positive coefficient in the bottom row to enter our basis, and found any constraint row where its coefficient is non-zero, then we will improve our solution by pivoting on such a row, are increasing a variable with positive coefficient in the objective function, and decreasing a variable with coefficient $0$ in the basis function. Is this step then just for efficiency?

Thank you very much for your time :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: For a given/chosen column ($j^*$) you maximize the increase of the objective function by following this rule "$\textrm{choose i  to minimize} \large{\frac{a_{i0}}{a_{ij^*}}}$"

Comment: ah okay, thank you. So if we didn't take this step, we would still get to the right answer, just perhaps slower, as we would still be moving to an improved basic feasible solution

Comment: That´s right, Ethan.